# How do cross endorsements work house elections in US?

Tags: united-states, congress

I was just examining data on House elections (http://www.fec.gov/pubrec/fe2014/federalelections2014.shtml) and it seemed that for certain states the same individual was listed as running under two separate parties for the same district [specially the states CT, NY, SC]. The individuals appear to receive a separate count for the two parties they represent, which is then aggregated (typically the individual is running as a democrat/republican with what appears to be a cross-endorsements is from e.g. "Working Families").

My question is, is it the case that cross-endorsements only available in certain states, and does the person's name only appear once on the ballot or multiple times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In New York, this is the result of [electoral fusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electoral_fusion).  Candidates can run for as many established parties as they want.  The parties choose the selection process (primary, convention, etc.).  For tactical reasons, parties may choose a major party candidate to run on their line.

The [sample ballots](http://www.usabilityinciviclife.org/hello-new-york-what-will-your-ballot-look-like-in-november/) I found show candidates appearing multiple times, once for each party.  Votes are pooled afterward.

Only eight states are listed as fusion states in the first link, including New York, Connecticut, and South Carolina.

The rules are definitely different per state.  For example, in [California](http://www.sos.ca.gov/elections/primary-elections-california/), only the top two candidates, regardless of party, appear on the ballot in November.  Candidates may only select one party preference.  Note that presidential primary rules are different from other primaries in California.